# iOS get UTC timestamp

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, date, timestamp

I would like to get UTC timestamp. I cant do it like this `[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];` becouse it returns timestamp in local timezone. How can I get timestamp in UTC in iOS?

## Edit

Solved I can use `[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];` :)

Comment: In which timezone do you want your timestamp?

Comment: I dont want to any timezone ;) I just want UNIX TIME STAMP. If i understand it properly there is no timezones in UNIX TIME STAMP.

Comment: So how timeIntervalSince1970 can return the timestamp in local timezone? :P

Comment: OMG im so dump :), nevermind. I just work to much today :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

See answer by Pawel here: [Get current date in milliseconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150422/get-current-date-in-milliseconds)

He refers to using `CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();`

which is documented [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFTimeUtils/Reference/reference.html).

Since it is the system time, just correct for time interval offset to GMT.

Nevertheless using your code works as well if you correct for the local timezone.

You get the timezone offset by calling

```
[[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone] secondsFromGMT];
```

or

```
[[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone] secondsFromGMTForDate:[NSDate date]];
```

Comment: See the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14592556/objective-c-how-can-i-get-the-current-date-in-utc-timezone as well.

Answer (score 7):

**Swift Solution**

Use `timeIntervalSince1970` to get UTC timestamp.

```
let secondsSince1970: TimeInterval = Date().timeIntervalSince1970
```

If you want to work with timezones, use `DateFormatter`.

```
let date = Date()
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z"

dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
print(dateFormatter.string(from: date))
// output: 2019-01-10 00:24:12 GMT

dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "America/Los_Angeles")
print(dateFormatter.string(from: date)) 
// output: 2019-01-09 16:24:12 PST
```

Answer (score 6):

Just timeIntervalSince1970 returns UTC time as a double (NSTimeInterval)

To get a 32 bit representation (maybe for interaction with embedded systems):

`time_t timestamp = (time_t)[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];`